# AngularJS Form is not working, $scope.submit. undefined error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I have simple angularJS app, which got module, controller, service and directive; along with template html page which holds form variable and structure and print inside main html page index.page using directive which is working fine. Now I have ng-submit="submitForm() in form but I cannot see any data when I press submit; in firefox firebug its says undefined $scope.submitForm.Employee

full detail are as following;

```
Error: $scope.submitForm.employee is undefined
efController/$scope.submitForm@http://localhost:59662/App/EmployeeForm /efController.js:17:13
anonymous/fn@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js line 213 >    Function:2:218
Ic[b]</<.compile/</</e@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js:254:74
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js:133:309
lf/this.$get</r.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js:134:12
Ic[b]</<.compile/</<@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js:254:124
If@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:365
Hf/d@http://localhost:59662/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:314
```

### AngularFormsApp.js (module)

```
var angularFormsModule = angular.module('angularFormsApp', []);
```

### efController.js (controller)

```
angularFormsModule.controller('efController',
function efController($scope, efService) {

    $scope.employee = efService.employee;

    $scope.departments = [
         "Engineering",
         "Marketing",
         "Finance",
         "Admin",
         "IT"
    ];

    $scope.submitForm = function () {

       ????????????????????
    }
});
```

### efService.js (service)

```
angularFormsModule.factory('efService',
function efService() {

    return {
        employee: {
            fullName: "Khurram Zahid",
            notes: "The top employee",
            department: "IT",
            perkCar: true,
            perkStock: false,
            perkSixWeeks: true,
            payrollType: "none"
        }
    }
});
```

### efDirective.js (directive)

```
angularFormsModule.directive('employeeForm',
function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'App/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html'
    }
});
```

### efTemplate.html (form)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role ="form" ng-submit="submitForm()">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fullName" >Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.fullName" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="notes">Notes</label>
    <textarea name="notes" id="notes" class="form-control" rows="5" cols="50" ng-model="employee.notes"></textarea>
</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="department">Department</label>
        <select name="department" id="department" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.department" ng-options="dept for dept in departments">   </select>
    </div>

    <br />

    <span><b>Perks</b></span>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="perkCar" ng-model="employee.perkCar"/>Company Car</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="perkStock" ng-model="employee.perkStock"/>Stock</label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="perkSixWeeks" ng-model="employee.perkSixWeeks"/>Six Weeks Leave</label>
    </div>

    <div class="radio-inline">
        <label><input type="radio" name="payrollType" value="W-2" ng-model="employee.payrollType"> W-2</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="payrollType" value="1099" ng-model="employee.payrollType"> 1099</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="payrollType" value="none" ng-model="employee.payrollType"> None</label>
    </div>

<br/><br />

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

### Main HTML Page (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularFormsApp">
<head>
 <title>Angular Form</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="App/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
  <script src="App/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script> 
  <script src="App/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="App/EmployeeForm/efService.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body class="container">

 <h1>Test AngularJS App Approach</h1>

 <div ng-controller="efController" >

    <employee-form />

</div>
```

The above code shows all data correctly that is define in efService for employee

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a property of an object, but submitForm is a function. That will never work :-)

Comment: if you look at angularJS example, they are doing same way ... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in one of comments, you can NOT get properties of a function itself:

`$scope.submitForm.employee` - not going to work, since `$scope.submitForm` is a function

What you can do, accessing 'FormController' of your form. You need to give name for your form `name="employeeData"` and names for each input `name="perkStock"`

Then in 'efController' you can access 'employeeData' object, which is 'FormController'. This object has tons of useful properties: `$valid, $dirty , etc.` + every input by it's name, with their own properties: `$viewValue, $modelValue, etc.`

Or you can just use `$scope.employee` since there is two way binding through `ng-model="employee.perkStock"`- which we have for each input

Here is working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/bsL2vLZCAihbbDFO3Xp0?p=preview) with your code.

From controller, printing our form data:

```
$scope.submitForm = function (employeeData) {

   console.log('Printing "FormController" object, which is accesible through $scope, or might be passed as submit function parametr.')
   console.log(employeeData); 
   console.log($scope.employeeData);

   console.log('Printing employee object, which is binded through ng-model ')
   console.log($scope.employee)
}
```